# Check if form-posted variable is existing in one of MySql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a html form that posts a Class Number value  Ex. 150701-003

In my php action file, I want to check if the variable $class_number is already in the MySql table column named CLASS NO.

```
$class_number = $_POST['class'];
                 echo $class_number;

                  $check_class_number = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Academy.COLUMNS 
                  WHERE ClassNumber = '$class_number' ");

                  if(count($check_class_number)>0){
                    echo "exists";
                  }
                  else{
                  echo "It does not exist.";
                  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79546/discussion-on-question-by-mazen-check-if-form-posted-variable-is-existing-in-one).

Answer (score 2):

Give the following a try:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Academy.COLUMNS 
                              WHERE ClassNumber = '$class_number'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // the number does not exist so do whatever you wish
} else {
    // post an error message
}
```

Comment: Nota on my editing your answer: Enter code, highlight it all, then press CTRL-K and it will indent the code for you. Then just click on "Post your answer" or "Save Edits".

Comment: your code gives me a positive number even if it's not there in the table!

Comment: that will query twice I guess mysql_num_rows is a mysql command...an optimized approach would be to use the size of the array

Comment: how to use the size of the array?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $check_class_number = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Academy.COLUMNS 
 WHERE Class_Number = '$class_number' ");

if(count($check_class_number)>0){
    echo "exists";
 //do whatever you want to do
}
else{
  echo "It does not exist.";
}
```

Comment: this code gives me "exists" even if it's not!

Comment: count checks the size of array... run the query by echoing "SELECT * FROM Academy.COLUMNS 
 WHERE Class_Number = '$class_number' " and execute this..see if you are getting result or not..

Comment: you forgot the dollar sign for the variable. Otherwise, `check_class_number` is treated as a constant. I made an edit.

Comment: gives me "exists" in whatever situation :(

Comment: copy and paste your code again

Comment: still giving me exits all the time :(

Comment: execute this and tell me what does it give you SELECT * FROM Academy.COLUMNS 
 WHERE Class_Number = '' ??

Answer (score 0):

use the [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) property.

```
if( $check_class_number->num_rows > 0 ){
//yes
} else {
//no
}
```